# Doctrine2 Can't update owning side in a Many-to-one bidirectional relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a bidirectional association between entity "Task" and entity "User".

"Task" is defined as follows

```
class Task 
{
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="tasks")
     */
     private user;
}
```

And "User" is defined as

```
class User 
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Task", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $tasks;

}
```

Accessing relationship from both directions works fine. The problem is that I can't update the "Task" entity once it's defined.

Here is a test case

```
    $task->setStatus(new Status(2))
    $em->flush();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `setStatus` do? Why do you think it's problem related to user-task relationship?

Comment: From where status came ? :p you were talking about user and task, and suddenly asking question regarding status :p , it make confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to persist the task object before flush like this: `$em->persist($task);` then you'll be able to flush.

Read [how to work with doctrine associations.](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#establishing-associations)